# Spring MVC return redirect not working once I receive form data

Tags: spring-boot

Can anyone review why the return redirect is not working? My "/" route displays a form - I am using jQuery to stringify the user inputs and sending it to "/login" and successfully receiivng it (verified using system.out.println) - afte that, when I try to redirect to /chat/{username}, it doesnt work. When I manualy visit /chat/john for example it works.

Even a hardcoded redirect,return "redirect:/chat/John" isnt working. In the browser's web console Network tab, I can see that it sends the traffic to /chat/John" but the webpage does not refresh.

When I try to redirect after a successful Ajax call in my JavaScript file, it works. However, the redirect works, when I have "both" return redirect in my Spring controller, and success:function(data){window.location.href='/chat'/{username}} in my Ajax. Which is wierd - not sure why I need both for the redirect to work

```java
@RequestMapping(headers = "Content-Type=application/json",value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String message(@RequestBody List<Map<String, String>> formData, Model model) {
        String username=null;
        Map<String, String> formInputs = new HashMap<String, String>();


        for (Map<String, String> formInput : formData) {
            formInputs.put(formInput.get("name"), formInput.get("value"));
            username = formInput.get("value");
        }

        return "redirect:/chat" + username;


    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/chat/{username}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String chat(@PathVariable("username") String username, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("username", username);
        return "message.jsp";
    }
```

Below is my JavaScript file where I post the form data to "/login"

````
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form").on('submit',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url:'/login',
                type:'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify($("form").serializeArray()),
                contentType:'application/json',
                success:function(data){window.location.href='/chat'}
            })

            return false;
        })

   })
   })```
````

Comment: Can you try like that?   return "redirect:/chat/" + username;

Comment: Even a hardcoded redirect,```return "redirect:/chat/John"``` isnt working. In the browser's web console Network tab, I can see that it sends the traffic to /chat/John" but the webpage does not refresh.

Comment: What about this way? return "redirect:/chat/{username}"; like in here https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/redirect-passing-data.html

Comment: Does not work. Even a hardcoded redirect,return "redirect:/chat/John" isnt working. In the browser's web console Network tab, I can see that it sends the traffic to /chat/John" but the webpage does not refresh.

Comment: When I try to redirect after a successful Ajax call in my JavaScript file, it works. However, the redirect works, when I have "both" ```return redirect``` in my Spring controller, and ```success:function(data){window.location.href='/chat'/{username}}``` in my Ajax. Which is wierd - not sure why I need both for the redirect to work.

Comment: I used ```@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)``` in my Spring controller, and I no longer need to have the redirect statement in my controller and JavaScript is able to handle the redirect.

Comment: Do you want to write this as an answer?

Comment: @hattice I will do some more research before I unerstand why its  working this way,,

Comment: @ShyamGupta I have clarified your doubt in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that the Server-side redirect is different from your `windows.location.href`.

Firstly when you say `redirect:/some-url` in the server it sends a corresponding HTTP Status method (302) along with the URL to which it was redirected to the browser (jQuery API). The browser (jQuery API) then does a call to the redirected URL and it gets the HTML of the redirected url which is available as a parameter to the `success` callback.

So all this is happening asynchronously and finally, in the `success` callback you get the HTML of the redirected URL.

But if you want to reload the page, then you don't need a redirect from Server. The server method can just send a Success to the Ajax call and then in the `success` callback handler you can call `window.location.href` to reload a new page.